# Golang gob: type not registered for interface:

Tags: types, interface, go, rpc, gob

So I have a type `String` that is an alias of `string` defined:

`type String string`

I then apply the following method to it:

```
func (s String) String() string {
    str := "'" + s + "'"
    return string(str)
}
```

I then try to send a struct containing a `String` over rpc and get the following error:

```
gob: type not registered for interface: dbUtils.String
```

I do not define any interfaces with the same name, so why does gob think this is an interface?

I got the same error with a similar type but solved it with `gob.Register(otherType{})`.
This does not work with `String`, presumably because `string` is not an interface. I am somewhat new to go so please explain what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

It should work with String, but make sure you're passing an instance of a String() object, not the identifier String.  So use `gob.Register(String(""))`

Comment: This fixed my initial problem now I am getting the error: `gob: name not registered for interface: "dbUtils.String"`. Any ideas on that one?

Answer (score 2):

I think this may be a solution to what you're trying to accomplish:

http://play.golang.org/p/9OrSKfcCAQ

Note that you have to explicitly declare the variable as a 'String'. If you use the ":=" assignment will assume it is a string and ignore the function.

Comment: Can you summarise the content of that link in your answer?